# How can I attach volumes with docker-compose only when in the development environment?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the [quickstart: Compose and Django](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) page in the docker-compose documentation, both the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files add `.` as `/code`, like this:

```
ADD . /code/
```

And a few lines later:

```
web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

I'm guessing this is done so that when in development, you wouldn't constantly have to rebuild the image, and when using `docker build` the image is built with the source code already inside, so that in production, you could simply do `docker run` to get a container up. Is that correct?

If so, the question is, how can I create a `docker-compose.yml` to either attach a volume or don't do it based on whether I'm creating a production or a development stack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Minutes after posting this question, I came upon a page that had a few tips on how to do this. Here is how I think it must be done:

1. You define a `docker-compose.yml` that attaches the volume. However, in your `Dockerfile` you still keep the original `ADD` or `COPY` instruction.
2. You also define a `production.yml` file which doesn't include the similarities between your development and production systems. However, it does include the changes you want to make in your production environment. For example, the `volumes` section would probably be like this:

   `volumes: {}`

Now, when you run `docker-compose` in production, you do it like this:

`$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f production.yml up`

Here is the link to [Using Compose in Production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/) for reference.